# Chrome v35 desktop notification popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

Is there any fix yet for chrome version 35 desktop notification pop up ?

I have tried [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) also but no success.

Here is my code of html file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Notification example</title>
</head>

<button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function notifyMe() {
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }

  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {

      if(!('permission' in Notification)) {
        Notification.permission = permission;
      }

      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

}
</script>
</html>
```

This code is asking to "allow" or "deny" notification pop up. But not working after it.

Anyone else experiencing this problem or any fix of this?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You forgot to show the notification.</strike>

```
var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
notification.show();
```

**I have tested the code an works fine.**

Optionally you can register the onclick event to dismiss notification:

```
notification.onclick = function () {
  notification.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check allow or block status in browser. copy the following url and paste into your chrome browser.

`chrome://settings/contentExceptions#notifications`